# How to draw a linear map programmatically?

Tags: openlayers-2, web-mapping

I'm new to GIS programming and I'm using OpenLayers for my GIS project. I want to know how to draw a **linear map programmatically** between two locations from a real geographical map (may be OpenLayers). I think there should be a projected coordinate system for this. Is there any distance mapping algorithm to accomplish this task?

I do not mean adding a vector layer to an existing map. I want create a separate line map looking at a real geo map (Obviously a path connecting two locations).

**Original map**

[image: original map]

**Linear map**

[image: linear map]

Comment: what you mean by linear map? A vector layer of type Line

Comment: do you mean map where line is draw with heigth(y) and length(x) ?

Comment: Actually I can't understand the line heigth(y) and length(x). If it is geodesic line on map, that's not what I need.

Comment: you want to find the (x,y) at a specific distance between two geographic points? did you mean linear referencing?

Comment: or you simply want to plot a striaght line on the map between two points?

Comment: I do not mean drawing striaght line on the map. That's linear referencing. You 're correct. A map to show path between two locations with some linear referencing method. Thank you for getting me into correct track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using Douglous Peuker algorithm which can be used to reduce the number of vertices with a tolerance factor and generate a simple linear map while maintaining network topology. PostGIS ST_Simplify function has been implemented on top of this algorithm. There 's also an OpenLayers implementation of this.

Comment: can you share the code?. Also the openlayer method?

Comment: For OpenLayers, please refer http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13.1/examples/simplify-linestring.html
You can change Tolerance factor as necessary to adjust your simplification level.

There 're some PHP implementations also. 
http://www.phpriot.com/articles/reducing-map-path-douglas-peucker-algorithm

Comment: Also check http://www.loughrigg.org/rdp/

Answer (score 1):

I know that asking the questions is easier than read documentation and evaluate examples. Try to read source of http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/vector-features.html first.
For futere read http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/  with 'vector' keyword first and  books  recommended on http://openlayers.org page: 'OpenLayers 2.10 Beginner's Guide' by
Erik Hazzard and 'OpenLayers Cookbook' by
Antonio Santiago Perez.

Regards